# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages Authenticate Against Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing a site using ASP.Net Core 3.1 Web Application with Razor Pages (not MVC, not Angular). Unfortunately, when I created my project I chose "No Authentication". My organization uses Active Directory (not Azure AD) which I now need to authenticate/authorize users against and pull information from.

I have been been searching for 4 days and cannot find an example that uses this exact setup. Can anyone point me towards some resources that will show me how authenticate/authorize against Active Directory?

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use Windows Authentication. You can enable within Visual Studio or within IIS. Visual Studio go to Debug under Project>Properties